# Logical Volume Partition

Tags: partitioning, lvm

I have created logical volumes, using already existing /home /var directories...the process for creating the logical volumes was no issue, however after I create the logical volumes, all of the content in the directories looks like it was wiped.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: I do not understand "using already existing /home /var directories"... Which commands did you use?